# Как добавить список и выбрать условия

Tags: python, список, if

Начал изучать Python.
Пишу лёгкую программу.

1. Задаётся вопрос имени. Если вводимый результат совпадает со списком из определённых имён, то должен появится вопрос о городе (10 строка).
2. Если введённое имя не совпадает со списком (3 строка), то должно выводиться прощание.

```
name = input(" Введи своё имя: ")

if name == "Вася":
    print("Привет " + name + "!")

else:
    print("Слушай сюда " + name + "!" "\nПрощай-пока")
    pass    

city = input("В каком городе ты сейчас находишься? ")

if city == "Москва":
    print(name + "," + " на улице сейчас " + "температура" +
          " и " + "ветренно-безветренно" + "\nОдень что нибудь" +
          " теплое-лёгкое" + " и захвати зонт," + " ожидается-идёт " + "дождь")
```

Не могу понять как задать список в 3 строке. Ещё после ввода имени не из списка, всплывает прощание, но после задаётся вопрос города (а должна программа на этом завершаться). И ещё один момент - как сделать, чтобы игнорировался регистр? Чтобы не печатать каждое имя по два раза с большой и маленькой буквы.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Кажется, вы забыли привести код.

Answer (score 2):

У Вас неверная архитектура программы. Я буду итеративно её править.

Сразу скажем, что использовать `pass` следует только в тех случаях, когда у Вас пустое условие. В иных случаях, используйте `return` для выхода из программы или функции (или `break`, `continue` внутри циклов).

В python принято использовать форматный вывод. Поэтому следует пользоваться этой функциональностью:

```
name = "Егор"
print("Привет, меня зовут %s" % name)
```

> Привет, меня зовут Егор

В python3.7+ можно было бы сделать так:

```
name = "Егор"
print(f"Привет, меня зовут {name}")
```

Детальнее можете почитать [тут](https://pyformat.info/).

Длинные строки лучше сначала записывать в отдельную переменную, а затем -- выводить. Так лучше читается.

Следует понимать, что конструкция `if-else` имеет следующий смысл: если condition`выполнилось, то делай`A()`, иначе делай`B()`. Детальнее:

```
if condition1:
    A()
else:
    B()
```

Блок с условием -- это независимая часть, т.е. после его завершения программа продолжит своё выполнение. В таком случае, у Вас есть несколько вариантов решить задачу.

После проверки условия, сделать все действия, которые Вы хотите выполнить в данном блоке:

```
name = input( " Введи своё имя: " )
if name == "Вася":
    print (f"Привет {name} !")
    city = input ("В каком городе ты сейчас находишься? ")

    if city == "Москва":
        msg = f"{name},  на улице сейчас температура и ветренно-безветренно. \nОдень что нибудь теплое-лёгкое и захвати зонт, ожидается-идёт дождь"
        print(msg) 
    else:
        print(f"Слушай сюда {name} !\nПрощай-пока")

else:
        print(f"Слушай сюда {name} !\nПрощай-пока")
```

В данном случае, написан некрасивый код, который сложно читать: вложенные условия -- это нехорошо и обычно называется лапшой. Тогда Вы можете попробовать сделать так:

```
name = input( " Введи своё имя: " )
if name == "Вася":
    print ("Привет " + name + "!")
    city = input ("В каком городе ты сейчас находишься? ")
else:
    print(f"Слушай сюда {name} !\nПрощай-пока")
    exit()

if city == "Москва":
        msg = f"{name},  на улице сейчас температура и ветренно-безветренно. \nОдень что нибудь теплое-лёгкое и захвати зонт, ожидается-идёт дождь"
        print(msg)
else:
    print(f"Слушай сюда {name} !\nПрощай-пока")
```

Как видите, так -- лучше. Кроме того, я обычно не пишу `else`. И пользуюсь конструкциями, которые прерывают выполнение (о них я упоминал выше). Попробуйте в качестве упражнения избавиться от `else`. Подумайте, почему в данном случае лучше избавиться от `else`. За счёт чего логика программы упростится?

Чтобы проверить, есть ли объект в заданном наборе, Вы можете попробовать 2 способа. Первый -- это использовать `list`. Проверить, есть ли объект в списке можно так:

```
cities = ['Москва', 'СПБ']
print('Москва' in cities)  # True
cities = ['Москва']
print(1 in cities)  # False
```

Лучшим способом будет использовать `set()`, так как проверка наличия объекта во множестве производится быстрее. Сделать это можно так:

```
cities = set('Москва')
print('Москва' in cities)  # True
cities = set('Москва')
print(1 in cities)  # False
```

В отличие от первого варианта, второй вариант делает это мгновенно. Конкретнее, за `O(1)`. Эта запись означает, что проверка, есть ли элемент в коллекции `set()`, происходит без перебора. В первом же варианте будут по очереди проверены все элементы. Сложность последнего алгоритма `O(n)`, где `n` -- число элементов в `list()`. Про сложность алгоритмов можно прочитать [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/196560/)

И, наконец, для того, чтобы преобразовать входную строку к нижнему регистру, Вам следует использовать метод `lower()`:

```
print('Вася'.lower())  # вася
```

Вы можете добавить ещё один ответ с Вашим решением и мы его проверим и обсудим

Comment: Какой большой ответ, и не отвечает ни на один из двух вопросов автора...

Comment: @Xander Прочтите внимательно. Вы ошибаетесь

Comment: @PapiRUS У Вас получилось?

Answer (score 1):

Замените

```
if name == "Вася":
```

на

```
if name.lower() in ("вася", "петя", "миша"):
```

Здесь метод `.lower()` приводит строку к нижнему регистру, а ключевое слово `in` служит, чтобы проверить, содержится ли значение в списке или кортеже.

Answer (score 0):

1. Что бы задать список можно использовать такую конструкцию:

   ```
   name = str(input(" Введи своё имя: "))
   name = name.lower()
   list_of_names = ["вася", "петя"]
   if name in list_of_names:
       print("Привет " + name + "!")
   ```
2. `pass` в python ничего не делает. Как правило используется для пустого объявления функции. Поэтому программа не завершается.
   Используйте `quit()`, как вариант.

Либо заворачиваете кусок кода про города в функцию и вызываете в:

```
if name in list_of_names:
    print("Привет " + name + "!")
    "Ваша функция"
```

Тем самым, вы сможете отсечь не нужное исполнение кода. ИМХО мне больше импонирует, когда я могу `if` запихнуть в `def`(функцию).